# I have issue to search an exact word with space in apache lucene with springboot?

Tags: java, spring, apache, lucene

I am new in apache lucene and i have created a one application in apache lucene using Springboot application and i have problem to search a phrase query here is my search services so if any one help me. to search a phrase query.

```
package com.cygnet.lucene.component;

import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.Formatter;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.Fragmenter;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.Highlighter;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.QueryScorer;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.SimpleHTMLFormatter;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.SimpleSpanFragmenter;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.TokenSources;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class LuceneSearch {

    // Folder path where Lucene will create index files from #fileInputDirPath
    @Value("${lucene.indexDirPath}")
    String indexDirPath;

    public Map<String, String> searchContentFromFiles(String searchTerm) throws Exception {

        Map<String, String> fileWithRelativePathMap = new HashMap<>();

        // Get directory reference
        Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(indexDirPath));

        // Index reader - an interface for accessing a point-in-time view of a lucene
        // index
        IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(dir);
        System.out.println("MaxDoc:::"+reader.maxDoc());
        // Create lucene searcher. It search over a single IndexReader.
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);



        // analyzer with the default stop words
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();

        // Query parser to be used for creating TermQuery
        QueryParser qp = new QueryParser("contents", analyzer); // Change

        System.out.println("searchTerm::"+searchTerm);

        // Create the query
        Query query = qp.parse(searchTerm);


        // Search the lucene documents
        TopDocs hits = searcher.search(query, 10000);

        System.out.println("hits::"+hits.totalHits);
        /** Highlighter Code Start ****/
        fileWithRelativePathMap.put("totalCount", String.valueOf(hits.totalHits));
        // Uses HTML &lt;B&gt;&lt;/B&gt; tag to highlight the searched terms
        Formatter formatter = new SimpleHTMLFormatter();

        // It scores text fragments by the number of unique query terms found
        // Basically the matching score in layman terms
        QueryScorer scorer = new QueryScorer(query);

        // used to markup highlighted terms found in the best sections of a text
        Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter(formatter, scorer);

        // It breaks text up into same-size texts but does not split up spans
        Fragmenter fragmenter = new SimpleSpanFragmenter(scorer, 10000);

        // breaks text up into same-size fragments with no concerns over spotting
        // sentence boundaries.
        // Fragmenter fragmenter = new SimpleFragmenter(10);

        // set fragmenter to highlighter
        highlighter.setTextFragmenter(fragmenter);


        // Iterate over found results
        for (int i = 0; i < hits.scoreDocs.length; i++) {
            int docid = hits.scoreDocs[i].doc;
            Document doc = searcher.doc(docid);

            String rPath = doc.get("path");
            String fileName = doc.get("fileName");

            // Printing - to which document result belongs
            System.out.println("Path " + " : " + rPath);

            // Get stored text from found document
            String text = doc.get("contents");

            // Create token stream
            TokenStream stream = TokenSources.getAnyTokenStream(reader, docid, "contents", analyzer);

            // Get highlighted text fragments
            String[] frags = highlighter.getBestFragments(stream, text, 10);
            fileWithRelativePathMap.put(fileName, rPath.replace("\\", "/"));

            for (String frag : frags) {
                System.out.println(frag);
            }
        }
        dir.close();
        return fileWithRelativePathMap;
    }
}
```

I have issue to search a Gujarati font if i use ("") at that time i search exact phrase but if i use this at time issue to search english font with case sensetivity.

Comment: which values you're supplying for searchTerm? could you give an example?